# How to distinguish drag and column resize operations

Tags: pygtk

I have made a simple application with the TreeView class. I have set the resizable property to true on the columns to allow the user to custom resize the columns.

Later I implemented drag and drop feature to enable reordering of the rows. Now when I try to resize the columns, the resizing signals the drag-begin and drag-motion and I can't resize the columns well.

Is there any way to distinguish the drag and column resize?